# python installed yet not found by terminal

Tags: python-3.x, installation, cmd

when I type 'py' I get the following:

```
Python 3.10.0 (tags/v3.10.0:b494f59, Oct  4 2021, 19:00:18) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

but when I want to e.g.

```
poetry install
```

I get:

```
Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.
```

I have downloaded both python and poetry and I am trying to install poetry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because in the poetry.bat file the command python3 is used instead of python

```
python3 "%USERPROFILE%\.poetry\bin\poetry" %*
```

by default Windows uses `python` instead of `python3` so it can be fixed by editing the bat file directly in "C:\Users{user}.poetry\bin" and changing it to

```
python "%USERPROFILE%\.poetry\bin\poetry" %*
```

or by editing the python executable to be python3.exe instead of python.exe